# Using $wpdb to update current post

Tags: wpdb

I have a function that expires posts on a date, and adds a check to the database. Now, I'd like the ability to "recycle" those posts with new expiration date, but in order to do this, I need to erase the _expiration_date_processed entry. Is the function below the best way to achieve this, especially in the case where there is a status change for multiple posts using quick edit? Thank you for any insights.

```
add_action('draft_to_published','gcpl_draft_to_published');
 function gcpl_draft_to_published($post){
  global $post;
  global $wpdb;
     $current_id = $post->ID;
     $processsql = 'select meta_value from '.$wpdb->postmeta.' where meta_key = "_expiration-date-processed" AND post_id = '.$current_id.'';
     $processresult = $wpdb->get_col($processsql);
      if (!empty($processresult)) foreach ($current_id as $a) {
       delete_post_meta($a->post_id, '_expiration-date-processed');
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was complicating this whole process because I wasn't thinking about just using get_post_meta().

```
add_action('draft_to_publish','gcpl_draft_to_published');
 function gcpl_draft_to_published($post){
      $exp_processed = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_expiration-date-processed', true);
    // check if the custom field has a value
        if($exp_processed != '') {
          delete_post_meta($post->ID, '_expiration-date-processed');
        }
 }
```